# Groc (Docco fork) using strip option

Tags: documentation, coffeescript

From what I understand, the `--strip` option of [`groc`](http://nevir.github.com/groc/) (a `docco` fork) is to allow me to strip out folders from the documentation hierarchy. eg. I have a folder structure like:

```
src/
    module1/
        coffee/
           submod1/
               xxx.coffee
               yyy.coffee
           submod2 
               zzz.coffee
    module2/
        coffee/
           submod1/
               xxx.coffee
               yyy.coffee
           submod2 
               zzz.coffee
```

I want to exclude all coffee folders from the hierarchy of the docs. How do I use strip to do that? Its not really clear in the docs

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can achieve what you're looking for with the --strip option. I believe strip only allows you to strip from the beginning of the path. I've tried "**" glob pattern matching and I couldn't get your scenario to work (eg --strip coffee and --strip **/coffee)

For general usage, I use strip like this:

```
groc **/*.js --strip modules/WebCommon/j2ee-apps/webcommon.war/javascript

# INPUT
# modules/WebCommon/j2ee-apps/webcommon.war/javascript/validator/validator.js

# OUTPUT
# validator/validator.js
```

However, the filename in the actual html file still holds the entire path. That's because the template uses projectPath and not targetPath for the title.

```
# "projectPath":"modules/WebCommon/j2ee-apps/webcommon.war/javascript/validator/validator.js","targetPath":"validator/validator"
```

Admittedly, Ian MacLeod (the author) agrees that it's confusing:
https://github.com/nevir/groc/issues/13